# Drawing Text (Custum text) Over image captured from Phonegap Camera

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, cordova

If this question is repeated then let me know the link of original question because i enable to findout the good link for resolve my current problem.

I am working on `phonegap(cordova2.7)  camera`  and making app for android 4.2.I able to take Multiple Picture's from my app.All image are saving in sd card.But I want to write name on the top of taken picture. i enable to find out how can i resolve this issue.[image]

I want to use only javascript, phonegap method,or plugins.i didnot require any java code.
I try to use canvas

```
var CAM = {};
window.n = 0;
CAM.changePicture = function() {
navigator.camera.getPicture(CAM.onPhotoDataSuccess, CAM.onFail, {
    quality : 100,
    destinationType : Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
    sourceType : Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
    encodingType : 0,
    saveToPhotoAlbum : true
});

};
CAM.onPhotoDataSuccess = function(imageURI) {

 var c=document.createElement('canvas');
 var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
 ctx.font = "20px arial";
 ctx.drawImage(imageURI,10,10);
 ctx.fillText("Hello",30,30);
var gotFileEntry = function(fileEntry) {

    var gotFileSystem = function(fileSystem) {
        alert(3);
        fileSystem.root.getDirectory("AndroidClinic11/"
                + CAMFUNC.folderName(), {
            create : true
        }, function(dataDir) {
            n++;
            var newFileName = CAMFUNC.folderName() + " " + n + ".jpg";
            fileEntry.moveTo(dataDir, newFileName, null, CAM.onFail);

        }, CAM.onFail);

    };

    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFileSystem,
            CAM.onFail);

};

window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(imageURI, gotFileEntry, CAM.onFail);

CAM.changePicture();
 };
 CAM.onFail = function() {
console.log("failure");
 };
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a javascript library like [fabric](http://fabricjs.com/) which will allow you to save images/text etc so long as you are using the canvas which is possible in phonegap. Here is the [documentation](http://fabricjs.com/fabric-intro-part-2/#text) for dealing with images. You may need to load the image from the drive depending on how phonegap deals with images from the camera.